# Combine Two Columns From DataTable

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, laravel-blade, laravel-translatable

[image]

I want to combine two columns in my DataTable. I have `name` and `surname` but I want to combine them and show just one column with the full name.

**Blade**

```
<th>{{ trans('labels.backend.patients.table.id') }}</th>
<th>{{ trans('labels.backend.patients.table.nom_patient') }}</th>
<th>{{ trans('labels.backend.patients.table.prenom_patient') }}</th>
<th>{{ trans('labels.backend.patients.table.date_naissance') }}</th>
```

**DataTable Ajax**

```
columns: [ {data: 'id', name: '{{config('module.patients.table')}}.id'},
    {data: 'nom_patient', name: '{{config('module.patients.table')}}.nom_patient'},
    {data: 'prenom_patient', name: '{{config('module.patients.table')}}.prenom_patient'},
```

Comment: What are the name and surname database columns called?

Comment: it s in french (prenom , nom)=>(surname and name) i want to combine them in same coloumn@Stormhammer

Comment: @haffis, you could preprocess the JSON object and make the necessary changes before initializing the datatable. If the JSON object is only available as an AJAX response, then you can to that in Javascript. And if you have full control over the backend code that is generating the JSON (in PHP), then you can do it there to... for example, the DB query can be adjusted to return the query to make it have combined field.

Comment: i try that but i doesn't work for me can you help me please?@asiby

Comment: Sure. But I need some additional info. Do you have access to the DB query?

Comment: Also, which datatable are you working with? Are you manipulating JavaScript code and using jQuery or are you doing it in PHP?

Comment: If using jQuery, then you can find some useful information at https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/column_render.html. It shows how you can use the `columnDefs` and the `render` properties to define a column that can be a combination of any other columns even with some calculation if you want. The example shows how to replace column 0 (the name) with the name followed by the age (hidden column 3) surrounded by parenthesis.

Comment: @asiby i am using with PHP with function __invoke public function __invoke(ManagePatientRequest $request)
    {
        return Datatables::of($this->patient->getForDataTable())
            ->escapeColumns(['id'])
            ->addColumn('nom_patient', function ($patient) {
                return $patient->nom_patient;
            })
            ->addColumn('prenom_patient', function ($patient) {
                return $patient->prenom_patient;
            })

Comment: I see. But with the small bits and pieces your have provided so far, it's impossible for me to provide any useful help. I give up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case I would create an accessor in your model:

```
getNomCompletAttribute() {
    return $this->prenom . ' ' . $this->nom;
}
```

I believe you can now just call `nom_complet` like it would be a regular field in the datatables.

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor

Answer (score 0):

i follow your help and i try to combine theme with that

```
public function __invoke(ManagePatientRequest $request)
    {
        return Datatables::of($this->patient->getForDataTable())
            ->escapeColumns(['id'])
            ->addColumn('nom_patient', function ($patient) {
                return $patient->nom_patient.''.$patient->prenom_patient;
            }
```